# returl not working for site

Tags: force.com, force.com-sites

I am trying to set return url for site after logout.

```
<li><a href="{!$Site.Prefix}/secur/logout.jsp?retUrl={!$Page.Comm_Login}">Logout</a></li>
```

It is working fine for one sandbox but for other sandbox redirected to `http://www.salesforce.com/in/?ir=1` instead of mentioned page.

Need your advice.

Thank you
-P

Comment: Is it returning to Salesforce brand page heedless of whatever page you pass to retURL parameter?

Answer (score 1):

I have done small change in href and now its working fine for me.

I have added site base url instead of partial url.

Please refer below line of code

```
<li><a href="{!$Site.Prefix}/secur/logout.jsp?retUrl={!$Site.BaseSecureUrl}/Comm_Login">Logout</a></li>
```